# Are there in-universe reasons reason why Dany wouldn't start her conquest in Dorne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Dorne is the closest place on Westeros to Slavers Bay, and Dany's biggest problem is getting fighters / horses / supplies across the Narrow Sea.

So, I'm thinking... **(1)** Dorne is vast and arrid. Aegon couldn't conquer Dorne because he needed long supply lines for his standing armies and the Dornish used guerrilla tactics to disrupt them. Well, Dany has the Dothraki who specialize in fighting in arrid climates.  **(2)** Further, many of the Unsullied need to do some killing (to be "bled") to finish their training. **(3)** Finally, the Dothraki / Unsullied / Second Sons / dragon army needs to learn how to function as a unit. Rather than quickly smash Dorne, they need to war game with the luxury of having live targets. War game until Dorne is smoldering rubble, then head north.

Any possible reason why Dany woudn't start her conquest of Westeros in Dorne?

Comment: in the books at least, Dorne supports the Tarygarians, so they would be a potential ally not enemy.

Comment: Hi konishiki! Welcome to this site. Your question is interesting but seems to call for speculation and debate, which is off-topic here. This site is not for all things which are fun to discuss, but for questions which actually have a definitive answer. Think about this: among all the possible answers you could get, how would you pick the right one to accept?

Comment: @AndresF. I personally lean towards this not being opinion based. The question isn't where she should attack, it's why not attack Dorne.  There are reasons not to attack Dorne just as there are reasons why any other location isn't ideal. I believe we can answer what those reasons are objectively.

Comment: @kuhl If there are multiple possible reasons, how would the OP pick the right one? Remember, this is a Q&A site where a "right" answer is expected.

Comment: @AndresF. There are multiple factors. One correct answer. It's a yes or no question.

Comment: @kuhl Ok, but how would you pick the answer with the "correct" multiple factors for the yes or no answer? What if several people answer "yes", each speculating on different factors? What if someone answers "no", with other reasonable factors?

Comment: @AndresF. That's just background for the answer. The answer is objective.

Comment: @kuhl Disagreed. The justifications for an answer are important; answers without them are frowned-upon across the whole of stackexchange. Anyway, if you disagree with the closing of this question, please take it to meta.

Comment: @AndresF. FYI, took the question to Meta. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9808/44294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this would be a bad idea.

- As you mentioned, Dorne is notoriously difficult to conquer. With dragons, the Targaryens had difficulty doing this the first time.

From A Game of Thrones Chapter 5:

> “Daeren Targaryen was only fourteen when he conquered Dorne,” Jon said. The Young Dragon was one of his heroes. “A conquest that lasted a summer,” his uncle pointed out. “Your Boy King lost ten thousand men taking the place, and another fifty [thousand] trying to hold it. Someone should have told him that war isn’t a game.” He took another sip of wine. “Also,” he said, wiping his mouth, “Daeren Targaryen was only eighteen when he died. Or have you forgotten that part?”

- Dorne is seperated from the rest of the Seven Kingdoms by a [mountain range.](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Mountains) This would need to be crossed.
- Book spoiler which may or may not apply to the show

  > Dorne supports Dany as the sister-in-law of the Dornish princess who was killed.

> A Feast for Crows Arianne chapter: She [Arianne Martell] narrowed her eyes. “What is our heart’s desire?”“Vengeance.”His voice was soft, as if he were afraid that someone might be listening. “Justice.” Prince Doran pressed the onyx dragon into her palm with his swollen, gouty fingers, and whispered, “Fire and blood.”

Comment: "With dragons, the Targaryens had difficulty doing this the first time." In fact, they never managed to do it. Dorne remained free for almost 200 years (apart from the few years mentionned in your quote) and only joined the Seven Kingdoms by wedding. The Dornishmen even managed to kill one of Aegon's sister **and her dragon**.

Comment: @ArnaudD. But Dany's Dothraki army would change that battle space. They're mounted cavalry whose home turf is guerilla-tactics in arid environments. The dragons deal with the castles. Dothraki deal with Dorne. And, Dany can show the Sand Snakes how "alpha-females" really act!

Comment: Maybe, but she doesn't have much to win in Dorne. Plus Dorne has not been involved in the War of the Five Kings, so right not they are one of the strongest part of the realm (the North, the Reach, the Riverlands, the Stormland and the Westerland are all more or less recovering).